# Boolean statement for multiple filtering Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filter, boolean, predicate

I'm currently creating an app in Swift 4.2 which I'd like a filtering feature in place which allows the user to select multiple filters.

I have an array of the currently selected filters, for example ["Low", "Unread"]. I also have an array of the objects being filtered. But I'm struggling to figure out how to apply multiple filters to this array, especially due to the objects have children which in turn have properties which are filtered against. For example object array holds bulletin.importance.name which is the property that "Low" would be checked against.

The following code is a boolean returning function which will get the filters to be used on the array of bulletin objects:

```
return (bulletin.bulletinVersion?.issued == true) && (scopes.contains("All") || (scopes.contains((bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.importance?.name)!) ||
        (!scopes.contains(where: {$0 == "Low" || $0 == "Normal" || $0 == "High"}))) && (scopes.contains(bulletin.read(i: bulletin.firstReadDate)) ||
            (!scopes.contains(where: {$0 == "Unread"}))) &&
            (scopes.contains(bulletin.signed(i: bulletin.signDate)) && bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.requiresSignature == true) && scopes.contains(bulletin.favourited(i: bulletin.favourite)))
```

This is my current attempt of the boolean check. I wish for it to be hard set so if the user selects "High" and "Unread" it will only show objects which match both of those filters.

The function is called here, getting the filters and filtering an array of ALL bulletins into which ones should be shown based upon the filters:

```
currentBulletinArray = bulletinArray.filter({bulletin -> Bool in
    let doesCategoryMatch = getScopeFilters(issued: true, scopes: scope, bulletin: bulletin, signature: true)

    if searchBarIsEmpty(){
        return doesCategoryMatch
    } else {
        return doesCategoryMatch && (bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
   })
```

I want to be able to set any combination of filters, where the returning .filter predicate will show only the bulletins which match ALL the filters.
So, Unread + Unsigned + High will show all High Importance bulletins where they are unread and unsigned.

Comment: You could start with https://pastebin.com/VFi1mFyT ? And you can create methods for `bulletin` to manage already some cases and that should lighten your long tests.

Comment: @Larme That's super useful. Thank you. I'll reorganise it now. Using the helper functions to test each boolean, how would I concatenate them together to make sure each Bulletin adheres to each check?

Comment: I noticed that bulletins have bulletin versions which in turn have other bulletins. Can you show some sort of screenshot of how these objects relate? Are these Core Data objects?

Comment: Are you asking for an implementation of the `getScopeFilters` method as a replacement for that HUMONGOUS cluster of boolean statements? Or would the `getScopeFilters` method be "in addition to" that web of boolean statements?

Comment: I was hoping to just use a huge combination of Bool statements to work for every combination. I realised this was not possible without smashing my head against a wall, haha. So I took out each check and placed them into a filter dictionary, checked if they were active, and apply the filters to the Bulletin Array. It works great now.

Comment: Nice. Please post the answer. People might vote for the Q or the A.

Comment: @JacobBarnard posted, I hope it's detailed enough to see where I made design changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to shove a huge amount of boolean combinations into one statement, I decided to place each filter into a dictionary:

```
 public var filters:[String: Any] = ["importance":[],
                             "unread": false,
                             "unsigned": false,
                             "favourite": false]
```

The importance filter will hold an array of strings, for example ["Low", "Medium", "High"].

When the filter buttons are clicked the filters will be toggled if they are a bool or appended/removed from the array:

```
if(!importanceToAdd.isEmpty){
            filters["importance"] = importanceToAdd
        }
        if(cell.filterTitleLabel.text == "Unread")
        {
            filters["unread"] = true
        }
        if(cell.filterTitleLabel.text == "Unsigned")
        {
            filters["unsigned"] = true
        }
        if(cell.filterTitleLabel.text == "Favourites")
        {
            filters["favourite"] = true
        }
```

Then, in a seperate function, I check to see if the filters are set, independently of one another. If so, filter the array fo bulletins by each of these conditions:

```
 if let importance = filters["importance"] as! [String]?{
        if(importance.count != 0){
            filteredBulletins = filteredBulletins.filter({importance.contains(($0.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.importance?.name)!)})
        }
    }

    if let unread = filters["unread"] as! Bool?
    {
        if(unread)
        {
            filteredBulletins = filteredBulletins.filter({$0.firstReadDate == nil})
        }

    }

    if let unsigned = filters["unsigned"] as! Bool?
    {
        if(unsigned)
        {
            filteredBulletins = filteredBulletins.filter({$0.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.requiresSignature == true && $0.signDate == nil})
        }
    }

    if let favourite = filters["favourite"] as! Bool?
    {
        if(favourite)
        {
            filteredBulletins = filteredBulletins.filter({$0.favourite == true})
        }
    }
```

The inclusion and removal of filters to a dictionary really made my needs more clear. Trying to create a monster of a boolean statement would have been infinitely difficult to be dynamic enough to match each possible combination of filters (I'm not even sure it would have been possible).

But thank you to all who commented to offer alternative solutions, you really helped me think outside of the box! :)

Comment: Yeah. It looks a lot cleaner than the conglomeration of parenthesized boolean statements in your question. Consider also the semantic clash between what you call "filters" and the `filter` method provided by Swift on `Collection` types. It could be slightly confusing for anyone else who reads your code. The keys for your `filters` dict are really just flags that are either "on" or "off". You might consider calling the `filters` array something like `tags` or `flags` to avoid semantic confusion. Not a big deal though since one is a method and the other an object.

Comment: @JacobBarnard Yeah I see what you mean, I'll make sure put extensive comments in to ensure no confusion. Thanks for all your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, but here goes.  First you could format your code to be more readable.... I know multiple return points were considered bad, but the tide seems to be turning a little on that. I would pick out the cases in order of importance and return any definite booleans you can find.  For example (untested code as I do not know what Bulletin and Scopes are):

```
func foo(bulletin: Bulletin, scopes: Scopes) -> Bool {
    if bulletin.bulletinVersion?.issued == true && scopes.contains("All") {
        return true
    }
    if scopes.contains(bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.importance?.name)! {
        return true
    }
    if scopes.contains(bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.importance?.name)! {
        return true
    }
    if !scopes.contains(where: {$0 == "Low" || $0 == "Normal" || $0 == "High"})
        && (scopes.contains(bulletin.read(i: bulletin.firstReadDate) {
        return true
    }

    if !scopes.contains(where: {$0 == "Unread"}) 
        && scopes.contains(bulletin.signed(i: bulletin.signDate)
        && bulletin.bulletinVersion?.bulletin?.requiresSignature == true
        && scopes.contains(bulletin.favourited(i: bulletin.favourite)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Note that each of these clauses tests for true and returns it if appropriate, so the function returns as soon as a true case is found.  The order of the tsts might have an effect on the logic.

I would consider creating a protocol with a method that took a bulletin, scope and returned true or false.

```
protocol Filter {
    func test(bulletin: Bulletin, scopes: Scopes) -> Bool
}
```

Then creating implementors of this protocol:

```
class AFilter: Filter {
    func test(bulletin: Bulletin, scopes: Scopes) -> Bool {
        if bulletin.bulletinVersion?.issued == true && scopes.contains("All") {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Once you have built a list of filter instances you could do (modified to match clarified requirements):

```
for filter in filters {
    if !filter.test(bulletin: bulletin, scopes: scopes) {
        return false
    }
}
return true
```

(Bonus: note how easy it was to change the logic with this design pattern)

Comment: Would this not return all bulletins which match one filter and all of another? So say the filters set were "Unread" + "High" it would return all Unread bulletins and all High bulletins? I will update my question to be more specific.

Comment: Reverse the logic then..... check for definite negatives and return false.  If you get through the list of filters then return true.

Comment: Change order of the conditions so that you can use `guard let version =  bulletin.bulletinVersion else { return false }`. It will simplify everything.

Comment: Also note that you can use `return filters.allSatisfy { $0.test(bulletin: bulletIn, scopes: scopes) }`

Comment: @Sulthan: both good points, and things I would do.  I was, however, deliberately trying to keep the code as close to the OP example as I could - avoiding distractions.